# PHP get arbitrary level JSON

Tags: php, json, loops

I'm trying to write a CRUD for an arbitrarily deep JSON array.

Before I used this - which worked -

```
get('pages','home','title');    

function get()
{
    $numArgs = func_num_args();
    $args    = func_get_args();
    switch ( $numArgs ) {
        case 1:
            $get = $GLOBALS['db'][$args[0]];
            break;
        case 2:
            $get = $GLOBALS['db'][$args[0]][$args[1]];
            break;
        case 3:
            $get = $GLOBALS['db'][$args[0]][$args[1]][$args[2]];
            break;
       // ETC
   }
   return $get;
}
```

But I really don't like that...and I'm hoping for something simpler, cleaner and more robust that can handle any array level.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create a foreach for arguments and just update a variable with data from each step in foreach.

```
function get()
{
    $numArgs = func_num_args();
    $args    = func_get_args();

    $db = $GLOBALS['db'];

    foreach($args as $arg){
        $db = $db[$arg];     
    }

    return $db;

}
```

**Working example**

```
<?php
    // dummy data
    $GLOBALS['db'] = [
        'pages' => [
            'home' => [
                'title' => 'Hello world',
                'content' => [
                    'text' => 'hello',
                    'title' => 'Rock'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

    echo "<pre>";
    // returns the title
    var_dump(get('pages','home','title')); 

    // return the content text ( example with more keys in array )
    var_dump(get('pages','home','content','text'));

    // returns the content array
    var_dump(get('pages','home','content'));

    echo "</pre>";


    function get()
    {
        $numArgs = func_num_args();
        $args    = func_get_args();

        $db = $GLOBALS['db'];

        foreach($args as $arg){
            $db = $db[$arg];     
        }

        return $db;

    }
```

Comment: what about the Save version of this though?
before I had - 
`case 2:
$GLOBALS['db'][$args[0]] = $args[1];
break;`
Which worked fine...I would still need to keep the rest of the $db though and just change the single value.
Any thoughts?

Comment: You say about updating the values from title for example ?

Comment: In that case the last `function` `argument` will be the new value ?

Comment: Yes...I use a `$value = array_pop($keys);` to get the value, but I can't update the key/value using that foreach as that keeps resetting the context. mmm...

Comment: Could you give me the function please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162873/discussion-between-funktion-and-andrei-todorut).